# How to optimize multiple simultaneous archive data requests on huge tables?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We are currently building a web-based visualization of some industrial processes which produce large amounts of digital and analog values that are all written into an archive table within the database. Each entry consists of these fields:

- `PlantId` (Integer, uniquely identifies one machine)
- `DatapointId` (Integer, specifies a specific value coming from a machine)
- `ValueDate` (DateTime)
- `Value` (Double)

The page for selecting and viewing these values contains a varying number (depends on the machine, usually around 12 to 20) of synchronized Dygraphs charts that request their data whenever the selected time range changes. Initially, the last 7 days get loaded. I use an Ajax get request that returns a native array as Json from my controller, which turned out to be way more performant than the CSV way of doing it.

When I only request one series of data, the request takes about 500 milliseconds to complete, which is quite ok in my eyes as the archive data needs to be selected by PlantId, DatapointId, a start and end datetime from a table with some hundred million rows.

The problem arises when I activate more charts and thereby requests. 3 or 4 requests still work reasonably fast, but with every additional request things get exponentially worse. When I request all chart data that need to be shown (let's say 15), it takes ages to complete, and sometimes requests get "lost in space".

This is my controller code responsible for retrieving the data for a request:

```
var result = db.ValueArchive.Where(x => x.DatapointId == DatapointId && x.PlantId == PlantId && x.ValueDate >= StartDate && x.ValueDate < EndDate).AsEnumerable().Select(s => new double[] { JsTimeStamp((DateTime)s.DateValue), (Double)s.Value }).ToArray();
```

*(JsTimeStamp() is a little function I made to convert a datetime to a unix timestamp (which is the native format of dygraphs).)*

I somehow have the feeling that when the controller method gets called too often resp. when too many DB queries are sent in a relatively short time interval, things get bad. One single request takes half a second to complete, 15 almost simultaneous requests take around one minute.

What can I do to improve the situation?

Comment: What are you using? EF or Linq2SQL? Choose 1.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tag: EF 6.

Comment: Try to add an index on the table ValueArchive with fields PlantId, DatapointId and ValueDate (and included column Value to improve performance even more).

First try this in SQL Server Management Studio and see if this improves your performance. (adding an index in EF 6 in C# code is a bit more work)

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, the index already exists (and you're right, it boosts the execution speed by about 100%). I think the problem is not so much the query itself, but the fact that many queries happen at once.

Comment: Then try to find where the bottleneck is, e.g. by using perfmon/task manager while doing 20-25 requests. Is it database CPU? Or database disk IO? Or network traffic?

Comment: Create a covering index. if the existing index only sped up the query by 100% that probably means the query is drowning in key lookup. Speedup should be extreme like 10-100x.

Comment: The current index already contains all required fields (the ones that you also mentioned above), there are no further dependant lookups. BTW: The database server is SQL Server 2014 Express - may that play a big role in terms of performance?

Comment: Hi, are you using simple action method or **"async Task<IHttpActionResult>"** method? have you checked IIS process performance?